# Using apple mdns service in android

Tags: android, bonjour, mdns

I downloaded dns_sd jar from here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/d/Downloaddnssdjar.htm and trying to use it in my android project to discover services.

I use the DNSSD.browse(myService, myBrowseListener) to discover services.

The problem is I keep getting

> com.apple.dnssd.AppleDNSSDException: DNS-SD Error -65563:
>   SERVICENOTRUNNING

Heard that mdnsd daemon is not always running on android. How do I start it or what is the workaround?

Note: I do not want to use any other library like jmdns, mdnsjava, waiter, etc...

Answer (score 0):

There's actually no need to use Apple's mDNS service because [Android Network Service Discovery](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html) (available in 4.1) is fully compatible with it.  I know you said you do not want to use another library but you must because there is no way to start the Apple mDNS daemon on Android.

Comment: I thought android already had an mdnsd daemon. Without it how would Android Network Service Discovery work? I just want to use the same daemon.

Comment: and Android Network discovery does not work well sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for starting mDNSReponder daemon:

```
context.getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);
```

More details [here](http://andriydruk.com/post/mdnsresponder/)